# Best way to globally set up alerts for when a Firebase location is changed

Tags: javascript, node.js, notifications, firebase

One of the things I'm using Firebase for in my app is to store user-submitted feedback - using `push()` to add children to a location. Ideally I could receive an email whenever a new child was added to that location, but this could only be done directly by some Firebase service, or perhaps somewhat indirectly by some Firebase service that could hit a URL (containing a tiny script that emails me), but I can't find any mention of either ability.

One thing I can think of is something like a little Node.js server constantly running and listening to that reference with `on('child_added', cb)`, emailing me when something changes. I'm using Firebase to try to build this app without having a server, so I'd rather not have to do that. I'm thinking of just having a cron job on my personal computer that periodically checks the location over the REST API. Any better ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easy solution is to use a third-party service. Firebase has really great integration with [Zapier](http://www.zapier.com). This service allows you to easily integrate Firebase with tons of different services and technologies without writing any code. One of these technologies is email. You can create a "zap", for free, which will run on their servers and automatically watch for new children of a Firebase path then send that child's information to you as an email. It's only takes seconds to set up and you don't have to write a line of code.

Comment: Holy craptastic, Zapier adds a whole new layer of awesome to Firebase. This is exactly what I was looking for. You can even have it phone you. The magic is here: https://zapier.com/app/explore?services=FirebaseDevAPI

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Zapier can no longer use firebase as a trigger. That said you could setup a [Firebase cloud function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) using Node.JS. There is a pretty good list of sample functions here: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples