# How to run cron job with Firebase?

Tags: javascript, cron, firebase

I am trying to run a cron job with Firebase. Basically I need to run a function that makes a ton of API calls and pushes data to firebase at 12:00am PST every day.  Is there a way for me to do this on the server side with Firebase?

I see that there's this module [here,](https://github.com/doowb/firebase-cron) but I don't understand how it works at all. If anyone has any ideas or know how the aforementioned module could work that would be fantastic.

EDIT: Idea. What if I were to create a data entry that showed the time that the function was completed.  Basically check to see that last time the function was called and completed.  If it's past 12am then the function is called and the field is updated so it's not called until the next day. Would this be a good idea?  I don't need the function to happen at 12am exactly, I just need it to be completed by the time the first user logs in.

Comment: Firebase only stores data - to run a cron job you'll need to have access to your own server.

Comment: @nathanhleung I just edited the question...do you think that will be an okay solution?

Comment: You'll still need to have something to check the data entry - most likely your own server

Comment: @nathanhleung couldn't I just check the entry on the front-end during user login?

Comment: Hmm actually that would work, you'll just have to ensure that it's run before the user logs in I guess

Comment: @nathanhleung awesome thanks! I'll give it a go and see how it works

Comment: That looks like a huge hack. I wouldn't like to log in to a server that uses my login to trigger a "Ton of API calls" that need to complete before I manage to login. Do not recommend it.

Comment: @phadaphunk when I said user login I really meant first user to access the site.  Still a bad idea?

Comment: Well it still looks like a hack to me. But it all depends you said " I just need it to be completed by the time the first user logs in" so if when the user accesses the site and the TON of API calls begin, is something preventing him to log in? Will there be any impact on the client? If so, I recommend building a little web server and using it to run this and future jobs.

Comment: @phadaphunk Cheers thanks.  I'm going to build a backend to do this now.

Comment: @ElliottMcNary, just posted an answer. Could you please check out if it would work for you?

Answer (score 33):

At I/O 2019 it was announced a new feature to do cronjobs with firebase functions.

Check it out

- [schedule-functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions)

### Snippet 1

```
export scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule(‘every 5 minutes’).onRun((context) => {
  console.log(‘This will be run every 5 minutes!’);
});
```

### Snippet 2

```
exports.scheduleJobs = functions.pubsub.
schedule(“every day 03:00”).onRun(async() => {
 // do something
console.log(“All done! See you tomorrow morning!”);
});
```

Comment: finally no need to deploy separately to gcloud!

Answer (score 5):

There are no cron job or schedule options on Firebase, you have to use another platform for that. Here´s one, for example: https://zapier.com/zapbook/firebase/schedule/

More information: [Best way to globally set up alerts for when a Firebase location is changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769106/best-way-to-globally-set-up-alerts-for-when-a-firebase-location-is-changed)

There are also some online cron jobs you can use, just search for "online cron job" with Google. Basically, they just call an URL in the specified time.

Update: There are cron jobs now, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56063698/757508

Answer (score 5):

Last month Firebase released the Cloud Functions.

There, you can trigger lambda-like functions depending on different hooks: Pub/Sub events, HTTP events, ...
They are planning to release a cron hook where you can trigger a specific function using a cron rule. It's not released yet, but meanwhile you can use [Google App Engine](https://github.com/firebase/functions-cron)

Comment: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html

Comment: Shame it's only available on Blaze pricing plan though... Not so sure about switching to uncapped billing while I'm still learning.

Comment: @ego therefor you can create a budget on google cloud. If you set the budget to 0$ you surely don't have to pay anything.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question about how `firebase-cron` works:

This module needs to be run on a server someplace so it's always on.
When jobs are run, all this means is that it takes the specified data for that job and puts it into the specified `firebase-queue` reference. As a user, you set up the [firebase-queue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-queue) to run when the data is added to the queue.

You can add a "cron" job by specifying the name, the cron pattern, and the data add to the queue using the [`.addJob`](https://github.com/doowb/firebase-cron#addjob) method:

```
cron.addJob('foo', '0 0 0 * * *', {foo: 'bar'}, function(err) {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  console.log('added foo');
});
```

Use the [`.run`](https://github.com/doowb/firebase-cron#run) method to start `firebase-cron`. This checks the list of jobs and executes any that needed to be executed. This method also takes a callback function that will be called each time the jobs are checked (I use this for additional logging)

There are some things that I want to add to `firebase-cron` and it's documentation but haven't gotten to them yet. I've been using it in production environments for a while now and haven't had any problems with `firebase-cron` itself... just user errors in my queue logic ;)

Also, I've been using the new Firebase Cloud Functions and they're great. I may add a feature to be able to trigger a cloud function instead of using `firebase-queue`. This probably won't be necessary once their cron service is running.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution 1

Back in March 2017 [Abe Haskins](https://github.com/abehaskins) published [an article](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html) on how to utilize Google's [App Engine Cron](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cron) to schedule cron jobs for Firebase. If you want to follow this approach, you will need:

- git
- Python 2.7
- Python pip
- Google Cloud SDK

### Solution 2

There's a cool tutorial by [Jeff Delaney](https://github.com/codediodeio) on how to make dynamic cron jobs for Firebase. You can have a look at it [here](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/scheduled-tasks-and-cron-jobs-with-firebase/).

> The goal of this solution is to provide dynamic task scheduling that can be managed both clientside and serverside based on user interaction. Let’s consider some uses cases:
>
> - Scheduled or snooze-able reminder notifications
> - Send a happy birthday push notification
> - Send welcome email 24 hours after signup
> - Retry tasks if they fail due to errors

### Solution 3

Finally, you can also use *free* third-party cron job services like [cron-job.org](https://cron-job.org/en/). It looks pretty straight-forward and it gives you:

- Execution up to 60x an hour
- Status notifications
- Execution history

Hope that some of these will help.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a free online HTTP trigger/request generator (e.g. https://atrigger.com/), one approach is to fire the cloud function upon user (client-side) interaction with your app.  A stored `number` type field could hold a UNIX timestamp. If that timestamp is greater than 24 hours old, continue to fire your server-side cloud function (and refresh timestamp) else stop/break/quit. Could be a week or month or whatever time interval you want.

What if no user interacts with your app? In that case, why update your app's data?  Regarding stale data for the 1st user, that's a matter of tuning your time interval. Also, you could possible alert the user that new data is being fetched and to hold on/wait.