# Is there a way to have a web application continue running even when it is closed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase-realtime-database

Suppose I want to build someone similar to an alarm, except every hour it performs a list of tasks. For the sake of this example, suppose it is to send notifications. I want the inner function to look something like this:

```
$scope.performTasks = function(){
    emailUserWeb();
    emailUserPhone();
    postToFacebook();
    postToTwitter();
    postToWherever();
}
```

So, assume everyday, this sends a notification at exactly ##:37pm. If I want something like this to run even when I am not on the site, how can I build something like that? Is it even possible?

Comment: yes - build this on server side.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is building a backend service that will run on cloud or your own server to perform the scheduled task

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35737708/how-to-run-cron-job-with-firebase

Answer (score 1):

Your Javascript is client-sided. That means it can only be executed as long as it is executed by the client's browser.

If you want to execute scheduled tasks, you need a server that runs the code (e.g., NodeJS).

Answer (score 0):

You can build it as Chrome App/Extension which will have a backgroud process, If you keep Chrome running, even if not on the app webpage, it will work.

Check: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages