# Is there a way to setup an self destructing value on Firebase real time database or firestore?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, self-destruction

I'm working on a web app with firebase as backend and reactjs, and i want to create an self destructing value or at least an boolean value that changes after 24h. Is there a way to do it with firebase or with another database?

Comment: You would probably need a server to run a cron job or something similar that's scheduled to sweep your database for expired values at a specified interval. Databases are just stores, they don't have documents that can schedule changes to themselves, there needs to be an actor on the database.

Comment: You can check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35737708/how-to-run-cron-job-with-firebase/56063698#56063698