# How to delete Cloud Firestore backup older than 15 days?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am doing a backup of the whole Cloud Firestore Database in the storage bucket on the daily basis. As our users are increasing, Firestore cost is also increasing.

Now, I want to delete the backup older than 15 days ago automatically. Is there any way by which I can write a cloud function that automatically deletes backup which is older than 15 days?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Besides the other solutions provided here, you could also add a **lifecycle rule** on the backup bucket that will `delete` the objects within it based on their `age`. You can set a condition that the object will be deleted after 15 days.

Have a look at [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle) GCP documentation article for more information about the **Object Lifecycle Management**.

Comment: I want to make sure one thing, this will not delete the live data from the Cloud Firestore Database? right?

Comment: No, the lifecycle rule is set on the bucket-level and will only delete the files within the bucket.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a corn job and run it as per your schedule, please refer the below URL for more details, hope it will help:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-cron-jobs-by-examples

Schedule job in firebase can also be a help:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions

[How to run cron job with Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35737708/how-to-run-cron-job-with-firebase)

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, you should be having a **timestamp**(*of its creation*) on each document.

Then you can write a function to **delete** the documents whose timestamp is older than 15 days which you can execute every 15 days or so by a [Cron Job](https://cron-job.org/en/)

Hope it works out!