# Firebase RealTime Database Cron Job

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I using Firebase Real-Time Database.
My example structure:

```
fruits:{
     apple:{
           soldAllTime:500
           Verify:true
           soldDaily:30
          },
     banana:{
           soldAllTime:350
           Verify:true
           soldDaily:27
          },
}
```

II want all 'soldDaily's to be reset at 00:00 UTC every day. What is the easiest and most logical way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is an option in Firebase. Its called [schedule functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions). With this, you can schedule a task based on time interval like every 5 mins etc., or based on exact time like every day at 12:00 PM.

However, you need to have Blaze plan in order to use this feature.

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56063698/7268308).